# Automatically inheriting title for image

Tags: media, files

Is there a way to inherit the title or copyright field in the properties of a picture on your pc to the title or alt field of an image in drupal?

---

What I want to achieve is the following:

I want other people to be able to write things on my website, and include a picture to the text. However due to copyrights, I don't want them to be able to upload images. They can only use the images which I have paid for.

This works perfectly, I am using a combination of the following modules:

1. FileField Sources
2. IMCE
3. IMCE for FileField

---

So far so good, but I also want to be sure that the credits are given to the original authors of the images. I know for sure that people will forget to write that in their text, so I was wondering if it was possible to do this automatically.

If the copyright or title field of the image properties would automatically be added to the picture's title in drupal, I could disable the title field & the credits will always be correctly showed. That is, if I add them to the pictures before uploading :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for although it uses Media rather than IMCE... 
http://webwash.net/tutorials/customize-media-module-image-display-drupal-7

Ok based on your comment I am assuming you have a directory on your computer called: 'images', that contains a bunch of files like 'image-001.jpg', 'image-002.jpg' and properties attached to these files ... on a Windows OS...

You can follow [the instructions here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/02/04/use-powershell-to-create-csv-file-to-open-in-excel.aspx): To export your 'images' directory and contents as a CSV (comma-seperated-values) file. This CSV-file can then be 'Read' by Drupal, and it will save you from having to re-enter properties attached to your images manually.

It's important to carefully format your CSV file in Excel  or whatever Spreadsheet software you are using (google docs is good at importing and exporting CSVs) so that there is at least one column with unique elements in it, e.g. Column 'Title' - > Image 001, Image 002, Image 003, etc...
Other columns can have headers that match the image properties, such as 'date created', 'copyright' etc...

You can then use the ['feeds'](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/feeds) module to import this CSV to Drupal.
E.g. you can create a content-type 'Image' with fields that match your CSV's headers...like 'Date Created', 'Copyright' etc...

This question will probably help you in making the last stage happen...
https://www.drupal.org/node/1851322

Comment: iain, does it actually inherit the title & alt automatically when uploading? Because I don't find anything about that. So I guess it's not what I want. I don't want something where you write it manually, I already have that. I want it to inherit the title & copyright form the properties in windows itself so that I never have to write the title or alt text in drupal.

Also, media is only available from 7.9, I have drupal 7.7 and not yet ready to update sadly enough :(

Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Oh, Ok, well in your files as they exist on windows where is the copyright information stored?

Comment: The copyright is in this windows (last thing in the second part)

It's the normal properties window of windows.

 http://i.stack.imgur.com/MLlPt.png


PS: Thanks for your solution, but that's not what I'm looking for, I also thought of that, but that would mean I would have to add what... 500 CSV's a day? I have way too many pictures that I have to add and the copyrights have to be there immediately. That's why I'm looking for an automated way of doing this.

Comment: Ok, I think the method mentioned in my above post will grab this info and put it into the CSV. Alternately, if you are more comfortable useing adobe this might help: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/493999

...you'd just need one CSV and using feeds you can set periodic updates for your content from the CSV file.